# CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes returns -6661 (kCVReturnInvalidArgument)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-video

I am trying to make a deep copy of a `CVPixelBuffer`. I receive the error `kCVReturnInvalidArgument` or value -661. I have verified the type of each argument and the length of the arrays and I cannot find what I've coded wrongly. I hope someone will spot it.

Here is the code:

```
func clonePixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let numberOfPlanes = CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(pixelBuffer)
    var planeBaseAddresses = [UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>]()
    var planeWidths = [Int]()
    var planeHeights = [Int]()
    var planeBytesPerRows = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<numberOfPlanes {
        planeBaseAddresses.append(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0))
        planeWidths.append(CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, i))
        planeHeights.append(CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, i))
        planeBytesPerRows.append(CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, i))
    }
    let newPixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>()
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(nil, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, nil, 0, numberOfPlanes, &planeBaseAddresses, &planeWidths, &planeHeights, &planeBytesPerRows, nil, nil, nil, newPixelBuffer)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
    if status == noErr { <------ status = -6661
        return newPixelBuffer.memory
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised to find that the compiler lets you pass arrays/lists of *Int* to arguments where `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>` is expected. Are you sure this is automatically and correctly converted?

Comment: Yes, this is legal. It explains it in the Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective C Guide.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is it, but there's a copypaste error on the bytesPerRows line -- it says

```
planeBytesPerRows.append(CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, i))
```

but should be

```
planeBytesPerRows.append(CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, i))
```

You might as well forward FormatType too instead of hard-coding it.

As far as I've understood CVPixelBufferRef, this won't actually copy the pixel buffer's data, only reference the data in one PixelBuffer to that of the other PixelBuffer. You would need to malloc your own region of memory for the planes, reference the data in that range, and then provide a Free callback function to `free()` that memory once the CVPixelBufferRef is destroyed.